# Dúvida com Relacionamento - Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Sou novo com `Laravel` e `PHP` e estou tentando criar um simples sistema de votação. Acontece que, estou com dúvidas de como relacionar entre minhas tabelas.

*Por exemplo:*

Tenho a tabela de `Pessoa` e a tabela de `Projeto`, as duas contém apenas `id` e `nome`. E criei também a tabela de `votação`, onde vai conter o id da pessoa, do projeto, e a votação. Assim está a `migration` de `votação`:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('votacao', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('projeto_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('pessoa_id')->unsigned();
        $table->enum('voto', ['sim', 'nao', 'abstencao']);
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('projeto_id')->references('id')->on('projetos');
        $table->foreign('pessoa_id')->references('id')->on('pessoa');

    });
}
```

Tenho dúvida de como seria a maneira correta para relacionar esses `models` com o `Eloquent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Exemplo

<sub>**Eu utilizaria assim com a** `model` `Votacao`</sub>

> #### Migrations

***Projetos***

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class Projetos extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('projetos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name', 50);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('projetos');
    }
}
```

---

***Pessoas***

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class Pessoa extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('pessoa', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name', 50);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('pessoa');
    }
}
```

---

***Votacao***

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class Votacao extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('votacao', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('projeto_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('pessoa_id')->unsigned();
            $table->enum('voto', ['sim', 'nao', 'abstencao']);
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('projeto_id')->references('id')->on('projetos');
            $table->foreign('pessoa_id')->references('id')->on('pessoa');

        });
    }
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('votacao');
    }
}
```

> #### Models

***Projetos***

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Projetos extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    protected $table = "projetos";

    protected $primaryKey = "id";

    public function votacao()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Votacao::class,"projeto_id","id");
    }
}
```

---

***Pessoa***

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Pessoa extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
    protected $table = "pessoa";
    protected $primaryKey = "id";

    public function votacao()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Votacao::class,"pessoa_id","id");
    }
}
```

---

***Votacao***

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Votacao extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['voto','projeto_id', 'pessoa_id'];
    protected $table = "votacao";
    protected $primaryKey = "id";

    public function pessoa()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Pessoa::class, "pessoa_id", "id");
    }

    public function projeto()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Projetos::class, "projeto_id", "id");
    }
}
```

Comment: Valeu! Me ajudou bastante. Consegui realizar o relacionamento e entender melhor. Obrigado!